# Is it haram to talk to opposite-gender friends online?

Tags: halal-haram, game, internet

I play this game and of course it has all genders. I have made a few friends on there, and a few friends who are boys. Keep in mind that I don't know them in real life. Is it still haram to talk to them?

Comment: This question shows no research effort at all. I would strongly suggest you check out the advice in our help centre at http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to better understand the sorts of questions we encourage here.

Answer (score 0):

Salam, Being friend with some one has a psychical influences in your mind. If being friend with some one is limited at a group, it might not be false, but chatting with some one or talking via internet and ... that has effects like real speaking, you must avoid. All things refer to yourself, if Islam makes a limitation it is for you to have a healthy thinking and life. Fi Aman Allah